# In-place Merge Sort with Matrix: Challenges and Limitations

Tags: c, sorting, matrix, mergesort, in-place

I'm facing a challenge with an exercise for my computer science course, and I could use some assistance. The exercise prompt states:
'Write a function in C that takes a matrix of floats as input and, using a recursive function that implements the Merge Sort algorithm, sorts the elements of each row of the matrix in ascending order (without using auxiliary matrices)'

Currently, I'm attempting to implement the solution, but it appears to be ineffective. When I provide the following matrix as input:

```
float matrix[3][3] = {
        {5.2, 1.1, 3.3},
        {0.8, 4.4, 2.1},
        {9.6, 7.3, 1.5}
    };
```

The output I receive is identical to the input matrix, indicating that the sorting process is not functioning correctly.
I suspect that the issue lies within my implementation of the Merge Sort algorithm for sorting the elements of each row. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ROWS 100
#define MAX_COLS 100

void initializeMatrix(int row, int col, int matrix[][MAX_COLS]) {
    printf("Riempi la matrice\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
            scanf("%f", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void merge(float matrix[], int start, int mid, int end, int cols) {
    int left_size = mid - start + 1;
    int right_size = end - mid;

    int left_offset = start * cols;
    int right_offset = (mid + 1) * cols;

    // Merge the two subarrays in-place
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = start;
    while (i < left_size && j < right_size) {
        if (matrix[left_offset + i] <= matrix[right_offset + j]) {
            matrix[k * cols] = matrix[left_offset + i];
            i++;
        } else {
            matrix[k * cols] = matrix[right_offset + j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    // Copy the remaining elements of left[], if any
    while (i < left_size) {
        matrix[k * cols] = matrix[left_offset + i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    // Copy the remaining elements of right[], if any
    while (j < right_size) {
        matrix[k * cols] = matrix[right_offset + j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

void mergeSort(float matrix[], int start, int end, int cols) {
    if (start < end) {
        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;

        mergeSort(matrix, start, mid, cols);
        mergeSort(matrix, mid + 1, end, cols);

        merge(matrix, start, mid, end, cols);
    }
}

void sortMatrixRows(float matrix[], int rows, int cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        mergeSort(matrix, i, i, cols);
    }
}

void printMatrix(float matrix[][MAX_COLS], int row, int col) {
    // Printing the matrix for verification
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
            printf("%.2f ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int row, col;
    printf("Insert the number of rows\n");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    printf("Insert the number of columns\n");
    scanf("%d", &col);

    float matrix[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];

    initializeMatrix(row, col, matrix);

    printf("Original Matrix:\n");
    printMatrix(matrix, row, col);

    sortMatrixRows(matrix, row, col);

    printf("\nSorted Matrix:\n");
    printMatrix(matrix, row, col);

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried debugging the code by adding print statements and examining the variables at various stages of the sorting process. However, I haven't been able to identify the exact problem.
Any insights or suggestions on how to fix the issue and get the desired sorting behavior would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Unrelated, but C have had *variable-length arrays* since the C99 standard, over 20 years ago. That means you could define an array using plain variables, like `float matrix[row][col];`. This works well with function arguments as well. That way you won't have to worry if the user inputs sizes larger than `100` (in your specific case). But you have add some input validation anyway, because using user-input without validation is a good way to crash your program (e.g. if the user enters a million by a million matrix).

Comment: Hey @Someprogrammerdude,  I really appreciate the advice you provided. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Each row of the matrix is a 1D array, so the problem can be simplified to sorting a 1D array, and do that for each row.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Visual Studio C doesn't support variable length arrays and it is fairly popular. [_alloca](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/alloca?view=msvc-170), can be used instead to allocate from the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I have identified several issues with the logic in the `merge()` function, which was causing the merge sort to not work correctly. Additionally, as pointed out by @chux, there was an error in the `sortMatrixRows()` function where I made a modification to the calling function as `mergeSort(matrix, i, 0, cols - 1)`. By addressing these problems and making the necessary changes, I have successfully implemented the code and verified its functionality.

For reference, here is the complete and functioning code:

```
/*  Write a function in C that takes a matrix of floats as input and, using a recursive function that implements the 
    Merge Sort algorithm, sorts the elements of each row of the matrix 
    in ascending order (without using auxiliary matrices) */

#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ROWS 100
#define MAX_COLS 100

void initializeMatrix(int row, int col, float matrix[][MAX_COLS]) {
    printf("Fill the matrix\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
            scanf("%f", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void merge(float matrix[][MAX_COLS], int row, int start, int mid, int end) {
    int start2 = mid + 1;

    // If the direct predecessor of start2 is smaller than start2,
    // then it means they are already in correct order.
    // So, we just skip the element at start2
    if (matrix[row][mid] <= matrix[row][start2]) {
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise, we need to find the correct position of start2
    // and make a room for it by moving other elements
    while (start <= mid && start2 <= end) {
        if (matrix[row][start] <= matrix[row][start2]) {
            start++;
        } else {
            float value = matrix[row][start2];
            int index = start2;

            // Shift all the elements between element 1,
            // element 2, right by 1.
            while (index != start) {
                matrix[row][index] = matrix[row][index - 1];
                index--;
            }
            matrix[row][start] = value;

            // Update all the pointers
            start++;
            mid++;
            start2++;
        }
    }
}

void mergeSort(float matrix[][MAX_COLS], int row, int start, int end) {
    // The condition 'start < end' is the base case for the recursion.
    // If 'start' is not less than 'end', then the array has one or zero elements and is already sorted.
    if (start < end) {
        // Compute the middle of the array.
        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;

        // Recursively sort the two halves of the array.
        // The first half is from 'start' to 'mid'
        // and the second half is from 'mid + 1' to 'end'.
        mergeSort(matrix, row, start, mid);
        mergeSort(matrix, row, mid + 1, end);

        // After sorting the two halves, merge them into a single sorted array.
        merge(matrix, row, start, mid, end);
    }
}

void sortMatrixRows(float matrix[][MAX_COLS], int rows, int cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        mergeSort(matrix, i, 0, cols - 1);
    }
}

void printMatrix(float matrix[][MAX_COLS], int row, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
            printf("%.2f ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int row, col;
    printf("Insert the number of rows\n");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    printf("Insert the number of columns\n");
    scanf("%d", &col);

    float matrix[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];

    initializeMatrix(row, col, matrix);

    printf("Original Matrix\n");
    printMatrix(matrix, row, col);

    sortMatrixRows(matrix, row, col);

    printf("\nSorted Matrix\n");
    printMatrix(matrix, row, col);

    return 0;
}
```

I have added comments to the `merge()` and `mergeSort()` functions in order to provide a better understanding of their functionality.
Thank you @chux for the help and feel free to use it or provide feedback if you have any further questions or concerns.

Comment: Tip: More informative to print with `"%g"` than `"%.2f"`.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware that `%g` was an option. Thank you once again for your assistance and advice. @chux-ReinstateMonica

Answer (score 1):

At least this problem

**Failure to compiler will lots of warnings enabled**

Quickly found **wrong type** by enabling many compiler warnings.

```
// void initializeMatrix(int row, int col, int matrix[][MAX_COLS]) {
void initializeMatrix(int row, int col, float matrix[][MAX_COLS]) {

// void sortMatrixRows(float matrix[], int rows, int cols) {
//   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
//     mergeSort(matrix, i, i, cols);
//   }
// }
void sortMatrixRows(float matrix[][MAX_COLS], int rows, int cols) {
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    // TBD fix to next line
    // mergeSort(matrix, i, i, cols);
    // Perhaps something like the follow, yet now I am
    // getting into a rabbit hole of issues.
    // Moral of the story: enable all warnings.
     mergeSort(matrix[i], 0, cols-1, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had some distractions, but the solution doesn't seem to work. It's strange because my compiler didn't show any errors and the program compiled and ran fine.

Comment: @Davideh `sortMatrixRows()` still needs work.  The real problem: Did you enable more compiler warnings?

Comment: I actually don't know how to do that. I'm using Clion as my IDE and the classic gcc compiler with C11.

Comment: @Davideh I am calling gcc with "-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion".  I do not use CLion.

Comment: I'm going to install a WSL since I can't use Linux right now. I'll check what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Davideh Start by sorting a 1D array. That `matrix[i]` in the answer is converted to a pointer to the first element of row `i` of the matrix. Each row is a 1D array.